# Why do I need to use gcc -o string string.c cs50.c to compile?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compilation, cs50

When I was starting to learn C in cs50 course, I had a trouble when running the `get_string` function. It gave me an error saying `get_string is undefined`. I solved the error by  using `gcc -o string string.c cs50.c` in the vscode terminal and then running it. My doubt is "why can't i use the run (F5)".

I am a total beginner in C.

Comment: Short answer: Because VS Code is a nice editor but a terrible IDE. You need to install plugins and wade through configuration to make it compile as you like. For beginners that is not really a good thing as they do not know what they need to compile.

Comment: @Gerhardh _"but a terrible IDE"_ that is not fair. VSCode is a _source code editor_, no one claims it to be an IDE (it is possible to implement IDE features through extensions - but as you said, needs a little bit of effort).

Comment: @ErdalKüçük well, obviously people use VS Code as an IDE. And then it is a terrible one. No project management at all, etc. In the same way, a screw driver is a terrible hammer. It's not designed to be taken as a hammer but if it is, it is a really bad one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CS50 course, the `get_string function` is provided by the CS50 library, **which is a custom library created specifically for the course**. When you compile your C program using the `gcc` command with the flag -o and with both files, it links your code with the CS50 library and creates an executable file.

When you use the `run` button on Visual Studio Code or `F5`, it typically runs the program directly without any additional compilation or linking steps. Since the CS50 library is not automatically linked when using the "run" option, the compiler is unable to find the definition of the `get_string` function, resulting in an error.

By manually compiling and linking your code using the gcc you explicitly include the CS50 library, allowing the get_string function to be resolved correctly during the linking process. This is why you were able to solve the error by using the command `gcc -o string string.c cs50.c` in the VSCode terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much. And another doubt when i import stdio.h there is no error .so is it possible to use cs50.h if i take the file and put it in the same folder as stdio.h does that work??

Comment: Well, I haven't tried something like that yet, but you can try these small experiments instead of asking first. Also If you found this helpful then please vote for this answer so I can help others.

Comment: @Subin there is no error when you use the standard headers because gcc implicitly links them. There is no such implicit linking for any other library except for the math library on some systems and compiler specific libraries (such as libgcc). You _must_ explicitly link all 3rd party libraries.